# Error during Team Build: The type or namespace name 'Serializable' could not be found

Tags: .net, msbuild, reference, serializable

New problem with VS2005 Team Build:

Building locally a solution of a mobile client for a platform of the company, everything goes pretty neat and compilation occurs without major hiccups, but using the very same solution on a Team Build gives me the following problem:

> Solution: TB Client.sln, Project: Client.PocketPC.UIAPI.csproj, Compilation errors and warnings
>   EnumBackgroundImages.cs(10,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Serializable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have the [Serializable] attribute on other projects and no problems with it, having exactly the same assembly references and using directives, and they all compile on my local machine and the build machine, all references are ok on the build machine and such.
I have no more ideas of what to try.

Comment: Can you build the same project through Visual Studio *on the build machine*?

Comment: The build machine didn't have .NET Compact Framework SP2 installed, which sanes this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that .NET Compact Framework wasn't installed on the build machine, and it solves this issue about the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it would work on your machine and not on the build server, but your problem is that SerializableAttribute is not included in the compact framework.

Comment: And why that leads to the difference between local and Team Build compilations? Wouldn't it fail everywhere?

Comment: Check the declaration of SerializableAttribute on your machine, see if it is a custom class in your project that was not included in the build server.

Answer (score 0):

If they compile on the build machine, then perhaps you forgot to do a merge to your production branch?

Comment: Actually, it was the opposite situation, they built locally, but not on the build machine.