# the type or namespace 'Serializable' could not b found

Tags: c#

I have an error on `[Serializable]` while having the `using System` also the `System.Serializable` does not exist for me.

```
using System;

namespace DataEntities
{
    [Serializable]
    public class GameType
    {
        private String name;

        public String Name
        {
            get { return this.name;  }
            set { this.name = value;  }
        }
```

this is my serialization method

```
public void SubmitGameListChanges()
{
    string serializationFile = Path.Combine(dir, "games.bin");
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(serializationFile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        var binFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

        binFormatter.Serialize(stream, games);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your project type?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356640/error-during-team-build-the-type-or-namespace-name-serializable-could-not-be and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383060/type-or-namespace-name-serializable-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system

Comment: the template? class library or class library package can't remember

Comment: *Portable* class library can't use `SerializableAttribute`.

Comment: Is this a "Universal Windows" project? (Serializable doesn't exist there - I haven't looked at alternatives yet)

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'd updated my comment to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: so what do you sugest i undertake, should i change template?

Comment: @MarkShevchenko i was using library class packages what for some not implements serializable, rewrote my code in class libraries and now it works, ty

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project contains a reference to System as well.

Comment: Please post this as a comment rather than an answer

Comment: If it answers the question it is an answer @MusicLovingIndianGirl. If you don't like it, down vote it.

Comment: i was using class library packages wich did not work with serializable for some reason, ty anyway

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't add the reference off serialization?

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: And which should OP add?

Comment: i was using class library packages wich did not work with serializable for some reason, ty anyway